# Can't create Tkinter window method

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code. This creates a dialog box just fine.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class Window(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master, padding=2) # Creates self.master
        helloLabel = ttk.Label(self, text="Hello Tkinter!")
        quitButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.quit)
        helloLabel.pack()
        quitButton.pack()
        self.pack()
        #self.create_widgets()
        #self.create_layout()


    # def create_widgets(self):
        # pass


    # def create_layout(self):
        # pass

application = tk.Tk()
application.title("Window")
Window(application)
application.mainloop()
```

How come when I uncomment the following two lines in the above code the code breaks?

```
def create_widgets(self):
    pass
```

I'm using python 3.4 32 bit on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I'm not getting an error message. I don't see anything in either a command prompt window when I run it from the command line and I don't see the GUI I am expecting.

Comment: I tried it on my machine, seems to be working properly. I am using python 3.5.1

Comment: I have 32-bit 3.4.3. Could this be a bug? I don't see anything wrong with the logic / syntax of code, do you?

Comment: The code seems fine to me , shouldn't make a difference if you uncomment `create_widget` method. Might be some bug I believe. I am using ubuntu 64 bit.

Comment: I think that the python 3.4 ttk.Frame (or Widget) Class has a method create_widgets(), which would be inherited and needed, but that you overwrite by defining it yourself. I can't find source code to support this claim atm, but [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=raErCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT548&ots=9BFsDrgTP7&dq=%22create_widgets%22%20python&pg=PT548#v=onepage&q=%22create_widgets%22%20python&f=false) that is suggested.

Comment: I renamed the method by adding an additional character so that I wouldn't be overriding one of the super class' methods and I got the same result.

Comment: Your code is fine. The problem is that when you uncomment create_widgets(), this later one is wrongly intended, so you need to fix that.

Comment: my create_widgets method definition is indented with only one tab, the same as the __init__ definition. Also I'm not getting syntax errors messages.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, are you literally referring to the code exactly as it is in this question? Have you tried copying the code as it appears in stackoverflow, pasting it to a new file, and then running it? That would show that what we are seeing is what you are seeing.

Comment: I figured out the problem. My editor converted my tabs to spaces and the interpreter wasn't reading it properly. I converted all the indents to tabs and it now works.

Comment: @Chinwobble how is that possible . Didn't it throw an error if there was indentation problem. Weird